# Maven pom.xml plugin not found. Screenshot attached

Tags: maven, plugins

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUvI1.jpg)

All the dependencies and plugins in my project were resolved when I was using my old computer. Today I had to switch to the new one, reinstall all the programs and clone the project from git again. Right now I'm kinda baffled on how to solve this issue.
I've tried reimporting the project, invalidating caches and restarting IntelliJ Idea, performing mvn clean install -U, mvn clean install.
Still.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities for this to happen:

- Do you by chance have a custom `settings.xml` (mostly found in ~/.m2 folder) file pointing to another maven repository than maven central?
- Versions of the plugins are unavailable or wrong?
- Internet connectivity :-)

My guess is that your "old" computer had a custom settings.xml file which is not present on your new computer (yet)...